# Can I use PROC SQL for Pattern Matching in Search Conditions?

Tags: sql, sas

If I want to return any values where TITLE is equal to E1, E2, E3,...E99, can I program this in a WHERE statement like I can with T-SQL using brackets? I tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
WHERE TITLE LIKE 'E' || '[1-99]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression:

where prxmatch('/E\d+/i', title)>0;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that works in PROC SQL but you could use PRX or a perl expression to do that. I'm not familiar with perl, so my solution would separate it out into the two components and check them separately.

```
 where substr(title, 1,1) 'E' and input(compress(title, , 'kd'), 8.) in (1:99)
```

There are other variations of this that may work depending on what type of values you may have in your data that you need to account for in the processing.

Comment: Thank you for your response!